# Zend session getting wiped with failed login

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

I have a problem with my `Zend_Auth` function.

I have a web app that prompts a user with a login box when the key in the `Zend_Auth` session times out. When the user logs in with the correct credentials the key in the session is reset back to true. However when the user enters the wrong credentials all the keys in the session get wiped and the session is longer valid?

I am wondering if the `Zend_Auth::getInstance()` function is wiping it to start a fresh?

Any ideas?

```
protected function _process($values)
{
  // grab data from config
  $iniTime = Zend_Registry::get('config')->inactive->session;
  $expireTime = $iniTime->timeout;
  $realIP = new Application_Model_RealIP();
  // Get our authentication adapter and check credentials
  $adapter = $this->_getAuthAdapter();
  $adapter->setIdentity($values['email']);
  //$pwEncode->encode_password($values['password'])
  $adapter->setCredential($values['password']);
  $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
  $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();
        $user->session_IP = $realIP->getRealIpAddr();
        $auth->getStorage()->write($user);
        //check whether the client is authenticated
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('new_session');
        // Set "dummy" key with expiration
        $session->key = true;
        $session->setExpirationSeconds( $expireTime, 'key' );
        return true;
     }
   return false;
}
```

Link to the auth function that calls the _process method [link](http://paste.laravel.com/5wQ)

Comment: what does your authAdapter do if authentication fails, because in your _process() function you just return false or what is your login controller doing if _process() returns FALSE?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick reply, here is the function that calls the _process method

[link](http://paste.laravel.com/5wQ)

It should just log an audit event and send back a json message to the user giving error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell you need to `_forward()` (*preserves the request*) or `_redirect()` (*new request*) back to the login, either as a result of a failed `authenticate()` in `_process()` or somewhere between line 60 and 100 in `authAction()`.

From what I've been reading it seems as though a failed login is logged and the db is updated but then ... nothing. No redirect, no forward, just a header set to 500 and a message generated.

Hope this helps. I hope I didn't miss it completely.

Comment: Oh I see so when the _redirect is used a new session is made as apposed just _forward()?